# Question regarding finding differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a bit of a general question in regards to differential equations. Right now I'm working my way through "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes (1972 edition)" by Simmons. There was a question regarding verifying that the orthogonal trajectories of the family of curves dictated by $y^2=4c(x+c)$ that asked to prove that substituting the opposite reciprocal of $y'$ into the differential equation does NOT alter the differential equation ( I state the question verbatim below for reference). After hours of trying to crack it, I found the solution online. However, after going back through my work, I noticed one of the expressions I got for the derivative of the orthogonal trajectory curve did seem to act as a solution to the differential equation originally obtained. So, my question is the following...Given a trajectory family $y=y(x,c)$ and its orthogonal trajectory $y_0$, is proving that $y_0^{'}$ and $y_0$ satisfy the differential equation for the family determined by $y$ equivalent to proving that substituting $-(1/y')$ for $y'$ leaves the differential equation determined by $y$ unaltered?

[Side question: After checking other texts, I also wonder why the same $y$ symbol is used when referring to finding orthogonal trajectories by substituting $-(1/y')$ for $y'$. The treatments I find don't seem to address this specifically? Is this in your opinions more indicative of that it's understood that it's a different $y$ and they are just playing fast and loose with the notation, or is there a more significant reason for this.

$Statement\;of\;the\;question\;in\;Simmons:$ Sketch the family $y^2=4c(x+c)$ of all parabolas with axis the x axis and focus at the origin, and find the differential equation for the family. Show that this differential equation is unaltered when $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is replaced by $-\frac{dx}{dy}$. What conclusion can be drawn from ths fact.

Comment: Is it related to orthogonality as $\M1\*M2 \=\-1?

Comment: It is indeed. My question though is whether or not proving that a given family of curves and its orthogonal trajectories satisfy a differential equation equivalent to proving that the differential equation given by the family remains unchanged (for the given family of curves above) when substituting the opposite reciprocal of $y_0'$ for $y'$ in the differential equation in the context of what I asked above above.

Comment: Yea that's what we were doing

Comment: We can simply check that by reintegrating the new differential equation...

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure how that quite answers it. Granted, as they are both solutions to the DE, it would follow that given integrating (assuming the right BC's of course), that they would both give the same solution curve since they both solve the same DE. What I'm asking is whether or not that is equivalent to the operation of replacing $y's$ derivative with the opposite reciprocal of $y_o's$ slope and showing the same DE still results.

Comment: Wait, I think I see it now. The action of the substitution of $y_0' $and solving for it shows that it is a solution of the original DE if it renders the same DE. Sorry I didn't see that before. Thank you kindly for the assist! :)